# Write a dot and appears a comma

Tags: math-mode, align, babel

When I use `.` inside align environment, a '`,` appears on its place. It is because I need to use `\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}`.

Is there any other way to make latex write a dot inside align environment?

An image of this comma:

[image]

A MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside
%,draft %descomentando produce el pdf sin imágenes
]{report}
\usepackage[headheight=18pt,a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm, headsep=18pt]{geometry} 
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
RT2.303
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to be a consequence of `\usepackage{nccmath}`.

Comment: Just add the `babel` package option `es-nodecimaldot`. See http://www.texnia.com/spanishopt.html .

Answer (score 2):

This is a consequence of using `babel` with `spanish` option. You can undo this by using `\decimalpoint`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside
%,draft %descomentando produce el pdf sin imágenes
]{report}
\usepackage[headheight=18pt,a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm, headsep=18pt]{geometry} 
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\decimalpoint

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
RT2.303
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```